# How can I use the (This) to target a class with slideToggle JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need to understand how (this) works. I have seen many different cases and instances where it is used, but used differently. I want to target only one div out of several that has the class name.  I can't seem to get this to work properly. I've read several answers in Stackoverflow, but still can't seem to target one class using (this). Thanks yet again for helping me.

the js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery('.expandCollapseMenu').click(function(){
      jQuery(this).parent().find('.menu_product_main_container').slideToggle();
    });
  });
</script>
```

the html

```
<div class="menu_category_category">
    <h3 class="basic_catolog">Beverages</h3>        
    <div class="toggle_menu">
        <img alt="" style="border: 0px none;" src="/images/icons/collapse_menu_icon_on.png" class="expandCollapseMenu {src: '/images/icons/expand_menu_icon.png'}" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="menu_product_main_container">
    <p>Menu Item 1</p>
    <p>Menu Item 2</p>
</div>
<div class="menu_category_category">
    <h3 class="basic_catolog">Lunch</h3>
    <div class="toggle_menu">
    <img alt="" style="border: 0px none;" src="/images/icons/collapse_menu_icon_on.png" class="expandCollapseMenu {src: '/images/icons/expand_menu_icon.png'}" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="menu_product_main_container">
    <p>Lunch Item 1</p>
    <p>Lunch Item 2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `this` depends on the context the code is in.

In the context of an event handler (such as the function passed to `.click()`), `this` will refer to the element that triggered the event (otherwise called the *event target*).

In the context of an iterating function, such as `.each()`, `this` will refer to the current element for the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

It misses one `.parent()`

`jQuery(this).parent().find('.menu_product_main_container').slideToggle();` with this line you get the `<div class="toggle_menu">`

So the solution is `jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.menu_product_main_container').slideToggle();`

EDIT :

Ok with the indentation we see better the problem. A solution could be put a new div like that

```
<div>
  <div class="menu_category_category">
    <h3 class="basic_catolog">Beverages</h3>        
    <div class="toggle_menu">
        <img alt="" style="border: 0px none;" src="/images/icons/collapse_menu_icon_on.png" class="expandCollapseMenu {src: '/images/icons/expand_menu_icon.png'}" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu_product_main_container">
    <p>Menu Item 1</p>
    <p>Menu Item 2</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have no more idea for your problem without changing the DOM.